# Why does TypeScript assume all properties exist when using computed properties?

Tags: typescript

I'm wondering why TypeScript allows the following example. I assume there's a good reason, but I can't see why. Can anyone explain the thinking behind it? Would love to understand this better.

Lets say I have an object that I'm storing a bunch of pet info on. I'll be dynamically adding and removing them, and I want to key them by name, so I make an interface like so:

```
interface MyPets {
    [petName: string]: {
        name: string;
        species: string;
        age: number;
    }
}

const myPets: MyPets = {
    ernie: {
        name: 'ernie',
        species: 'dog',
        age: 5,
    }
}

// No error
console.log(myPets.chloe.species)
```

I would  assume that TypeScript would say "hey wait, myPets.chloe could potentially be undefined!!" and shout at me.

[TypeScript playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8AKEwGdkDeAsAFDLnIDaADjgHJwC2EAXMrmFKAOYC6bxMhWEgmrdpx4BuUsOG5aCYBFxsOXENxlC5yON3EgArowBG0bcIC+pGyVIIA9iA7JGWHKrQe8yALyEshTQIMoCQbqizGwA5CHKMQA0EXIKEEoqsQAmjtxJKcL64gCsyTrIdnYOzriOADYQAHR1uQAU7th4jQgAFi1NaRm4AJTIQA)

Thanks!

Comment: Why would it say that? You told it that the property would exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You told it that for every petName there is a pet. Use:

```
interface MyPets {
    [petName: string]: {
        name: string;
        species: string;
        age: number;
    } | undefined
}
```

instead if you want stricter type safety.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a sensible way to do this safely. Guess my understanding of the computed property feature wasn't quite right. Not trying to declare that every single string ever exists on this object (not sure why it'd ever be useful to declare that), just trying to say that every string _could_ exist, same paradigm as usual, but _if_ it does, it'll have the following structure. So you could do something like `myPets.chloe && myPets.chloe.species`.

Comment: This is indeed a bit misleading, which is why I don't understand the downvotes. There have been proposals to change this behavior but it does not look like this will happen anytime soon.

With typescript 3.7 you will even be able to use `myPets.chloe?.species`
see: https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/cianba/typescript_370_will_feature_optional_chaining_ie/

Comment: Thanks. Optional chaining looks awesome.

Answer (score 0):

This `[petName: string]` is the culprit. You are telling Typescript that the property is going to be a string.

However you are not telling it **what** the string is going to be. It could be quite literally anything as long as it is a string.

Typescript has no way of knowing what you are going to use as a key, so it can't yell at you, otherwise it would need to yell at you *every time*